# How are chess boards updated in real time in Blitz and Rapid tournaments?

Tags: software, tournament, online-chess, blitz, rapid

In Rapid and Blitz tournaments, there are usually multiple over-the-board chess games going on simultaneously.

It seems many websites and live streams have access to the chess boards of many players, and are able to show the moves in real time.

How does this work? Are there dedicated people watching every game and updating the moves in the system? Or is it somehow done automatically? If so, how does that work exactly? And how are multiple websites or streams which do not seem to be affiliated with each other able to show the moves?

I believe the live analysis board is usually out-of-sync with the video of the players, so I suspect that it might be done manually, but it seems absurd to have an army of people watching each game and updating the moves.

Comment: Of course this isn't manual! The games happen on DGT chess boards. that are connected to the chess clock.

Comment: @double-beep You should write this as an answer!

Comment: @odinchess.com, perhaps let the op decide...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The company [Digital Game Technology](https://digitalgametechnology.com/) produces digital boards, sets and clocks which can be connected via cables or bluetooth to a computer running their free software which allows the games to be shared via the internet in real time.

For tournaments cables are required. More information on their tournament e-boards [here](https://digitalgametechnology.com/products/tournament-e-boards/dgt-tournament-e-board-walnut).

Comment: Thanks. After more searching, I also found how the moves are then relayed from the computer running DGT software: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/how-do-chess-websites-relay-the-moves-for-tournaments